# I got this error when add awesome_notifications_fcm package

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-notification, awesome-notifications

I added the lib awesome_notifications_fcm and when compiling if for android getting this error, havent even implemented yet.

```
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.utils.BooleanUtils found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.utils.CalendarUtils found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.utils.CompareUtils found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.utils.CronUtils found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.utils.EnumUtils found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.utils.HtmlUtils found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.utils.IntegerUtils found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.utils.JsonUtils found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.utils.JsonUtils$1 found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.utils.ListUtils found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.utils.MapUtils found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.utils.MediaUtils found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.utils.SerializableUtils found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.utils.StringUtils found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.utils.ThreadUtils found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)
     Duplicate class me.carda.awesome_notifications.core.utils.TimeZoneUtils found in modules jetified-AndroidAwnCore-0.7.5-dev.3-runtime (me.carda:AndroidAwnCore:0.7.5-dev.3) and jetified-androidcore-0.7.7-runtime (me.carda:androidcore:0.7.7)

     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 55s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33 // flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "app.fely.staff"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21//flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

pubspec.yaml

```
name: fely_staff
description: fely staff mobile app

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.7.1+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.0 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  get: ^4.6.1
  get_storage: ^2.0.3
  vexana: ^3.4.3
  flutter_barcode_scanner: ^2.0.0
  build_runner: ^2.1.7
  analyzer: ^5.13.0
  json_annotation: ^4.4.0
  json_serializable: ^6.1.3
  intl: ^0.18.1
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
  encrypt: ^5.0.1
  firebase_core: ^2.15.1
  awesome_notifications_fcm: ^0.7.4+1 
  awesome_notifications: ^0.7.4+1
  http: ^1.1.0



  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/images/
  #  - assets/svgs/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: Rubik
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Rubik-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

and i got this error when i implement the awesome_notifications_fcm codes inside to my project.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 64 in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.
: Error: Too many positional arguments: 2 allowed, but 3 found.
fcm_silent_data.dart:32
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
          _createdDate = AwesomeAssertUtils.extractValue(
                                                        ^
: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
assert_utils.dart:55
  static extractValue<T>(String reference, Map dataMap) {

         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 1297

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 23s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

awesome_notifications_fcm codes

```
import 'package:awesome_notifications/awesome_notifications.dart';
import 'package:awesome_notifications_fcm/awesome_notifications_fcm.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class NotificationController extends GetxController {
  static NotificationController get instance => Get.find();

  Rx<String> firebaseToken = ''.obs;
  Rx<String> nativeToken = ''.obs;

  ReceivedAction? initialAction;

//!  *********************************************
//!     INITIALIZATION METHODS
//!  *********************************************

  static Future<void> initializeLocalNotifications({required bool debug}) async {
    await AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
        null, //'resource://drawable/res_app_icon',//
        [
          NotificationChannel(
              channelKey: 'alerts',
              channelName: 'Alerts',
              channelDescription: 'Notification tests as alerts',
              playSound: true,
              importance: NotificationImportance.High,
              defaultPrivacy: NotificationPrivacy.Private,
              defaultColor: Colors.deepPurple,
              ledColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        ],debug: debug
        );

    instance.initialAction = await AwesomeNotifications()
        .getInitialNotificationAction(removeFromActionEvents: false);
  }

  static Future<void> initializeRemoteNotifications({required bool debug}) async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    await AwesomeNotificationsFcm().initialize(
        onFcmSilentDataHandle: NotificationController.mySilentDataHandle,
        onFcmTokenHandle: NotificationController.myFcmTokenHandle,
        onNativeTokenHandle: NotificationController.myNativeTokenHandle,
        licenseKeys: [
          // me.carda.awesomeNotificationsFcmExample
          'B3J3yxQbzzyz0KmkQR6rDlWB5N68sTWTEMV7k9HcPBroUh4RZ/Og2Fv6Wc/lE',
          '2YaKuVY4FUERlDaSN4WJ0lMiiVoYIRtrwJBX6/fpPCbGNkSGuhrx0Rekk',
          '+yUTQU3C3WCVf2D534rNF3OnYKUjshNgQN8do0KAihTK7n83eUD60=',

          // me.carda.awesome_notifications_fcm_example
          'UzRlt+SJ7XyVgmD1WV+7dDMaRitmKCKOivKaVsNkfAQfQfechRveuKblFnCp4',
          'zifTPgRUGdFmJDiw1R/rfEtTIlZCBgK3Wa8MzUV4dypZZc5wQIIVsiqi0Zhaq',
          'YtTevjLl3/wKvK8fWaEmUxdOJfFihY8FnlrSA48FW94XWIcFY=',
        ], debug: debug
        );
  }

//!  *********************************************
//!     REMOTE NOTIFICATION EVENTS
//!  *********************************************

//* Use this method to execute on background when a silent data arrives (even while terminated)
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  static Future<void> mySilentDataHandle(FcmSilentData silentData) async {
    Get.showSnackbar(
      const GetSnackBar(
        messageText: Text(
          "Slient data received",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
    );
    debugPrint('"SilentData": ${silentData.toString()}');
    if (silentData.createdLifeCycle != NotificationLifeCycle.Foreground) {
      debugPrint("bg");
    } else {
      debugPrint("FOREGROUND");
    }

    debugPrint("mySilentDatahandle received a FcmSilentData execution");
    await executeLongTaskInBackground();
  }

//* Use this method to detect when a new fcm token is received
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  static Future<void> myFcmTokenHandle(String token) async {
    Get.showSnackbar(
      const GetSnackBar(
        messageText: Text(
          "Fcm token received",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
    );
    debugPrint('Firebase Token:"$token"');

    instance.firebaseToken.value = token;
  }

//* Use this method to detect when a new native token is received
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  static Future<void> myNativeTokenHandle(String token) async {
    Get.showSnackbar(
      const GetSnackBar(
        messageText: Text(
          "Native token received",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
    );
    debugPrint('Native Token:"$token"');

    instance.nativeToken.value = token;
  }

//! *********************************************
//!     BACKGROUND TASKS TEST
//!  *********************************************

  static Future<void> executeLongTaskInBackground() async {
    debugPrint("starting long task");
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4));
    final url = Uri.parse("http://google.com");
    final re = await http.get(url);
    debugPrint(re.body);
    debugPrint("long task done");
  }

//!  *********************************************
//!     REQUEST NOTIFICATION PERMISSIONS
//!  *********************************************

  static Future<bool> displayNotificationRationale() async {
    bool userAuthorized = false;
    BuildContext context = Get.context!;
    await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext ctx) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Get Notified!',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge),
            content: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/animated-bell.gif',
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
                        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                const Text(
                    'Allow Awesome Notifications to send you beautiful notifications!'),
              ],
            ),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Deny',
                    style: Theme.of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .titleLarge
                        ?.copyWith(color: Colors.red),
                  )),
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    userAuthorized = true;
                    Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Allow',
                    style: Theme.of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .titleLarge
                        ?.copyWith(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                  )),
            ],
          );
        });
    return userAuthorized &&
        await AwesomeNotifications().requestPermissionToSendNotifications();
  }

// //!  *********************************************
// //!    LOCAL NOTIFICATION CREATION METHODS
// //!  *********************************************
  static Future<void> createNewNotification() async {
    bool isAllowed = await AwesomeNotifications().isNotificationAllowed();

    if (!isAllowed) {
      isAllowed = await displayNotificationRationale();
    }

    if (!isAllowed) return;

    await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
        content: NotificationContent(
            id: -1, // -1 is replaced by a random number
            channelKey: 'channel_key',
            title: 'Huston! The eagle has landed!',
            body:
                "A small step for a man, but a giant leap to Flutter's community!",
            bigPicture: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage-bucket/d406c736e7c4c57f5f61.png',
            largeIcon: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage-bucket/0dbfcc7a59cd1cf16282.png',
            notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.BigPicture,
            payload: {'notificationId': '1234567890'}),
        actionButtons: [
          NotificationActionButton(key: 'REDIRECT', label: 'Redirect'),
          NotificationActionButton(
              key: 'REPLY',
              label: 'Reply Message',
              requireInputText: true,
              actionType: ActionType.SilentAction),
          NotificationActionButton(
              key: 'DISMISS',
              label: 'Dismiss',
              actionType: ActionType.DismissAction,
              isDangerousOption: true)
        ]);
  }

  static Future<void> resetBadge() async {
    await AwesomeNotifications().resetGlobalBadge();
  }

//!  *********************************************
//!    REMOTE TOKEN REQUESTS
//!  *********************************************
  static Future<String> requestFirebaseToken() async {
    if (await AwesomeNotificationsFcm().isFirebaseAvailable) {
      try {
        return await AwesomeNotificationsFcm().requestFirebaseAppToken();
      } catch (exception) {
        debugPrint('$exception');
      }
    } else {
      debugPrint('Firebase is not available on this project');
    }
    return '';
  }
}
```